# DomXPath achar elemento com nome exato

Tags: php, dom, php-domxpath

Estou com um problema ao tentar encontrar um elemento com o nome exato.

```
<?
//...
@$DOM = new DOMDocument;
@$DOM->loadHTML($html);
@$finder = new DomXPath($DOM); 

foreach($finder->query("//a[contains(@title, '".$info[$i]."')]") as $link){
            echo $l[$i] = $link->getAttribute('href').'<br>';
}
//...    
?>
```

Sua resposta são vários links (pegos do `getAtrribute()`), sem problemas.

**Onde está o problema?**

> Eu desejaria pegar APENAS o que o `title` fosse igual ao `$info[$i]`.

**Exemplificando (note os `title`!):**

```
<a href='1.html' title="biscoito"></a>
<a href='2.html' title="biscoito bolacha"></a>
<a href='3.html' title="bolacha"></a>
```

Se o `$info[$i]` tivesse o valor de "*`biscoito`*", seria retornado:

```
1.html //oriundo do biscoito
2.html //oriundo do biscoito bolacha
```

Resultado desejado:

```
1.html
```

**Solução que necessito:**

Haver alguma função (que desconheço) que apenas filtre por igual ao nome, mas que não somente contenha. Porque preciso apenas onde o `title` seja igual ao *biscoito*, mas que não seja o *biscoito bolacha*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar uma solução para o problema.

**Solução:**

```
<?
//...
@$DOM = new DOMDocument;
@$DOM->loadHTML($html);
@$finder = new DomXPath($DOM); 

foreach($finder->query("//a[@title='".$info[$i]."']") as $link){
            echo $l[$i] = $link->getAttribute('href').'<br>';
}
//...    
?>
```

**Resumindo:**

Substituir `"//a[contains(@title, 'biscoito')]"` para `"//a[@title='biscoito']"`.

**Explicação:**

> O `=` irá apenas exibir o que for igual, ao invés de apenas conter a string. Justamente isto que estava procurando.

**Nota:**

Existe uma outra função que é `starts-with` (se tornando: `//a[starts-with(@title,"biscoito")]`), neste caso não iria adiantar em nada, mas caso possua o mesmo problema pode testa-lo. No caso de pesquisar por *bolacha*, iria apenas exibir um, ao invés de dois, por exemplo.